# How to change how fast an element spins in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation

So the element That I am manipulating has an id of spinning and a class of rotors

I can get my element to spin. I did this by using the css code here:

```
.rotors {
position: relative;
top: 90px;
left: 30px;
-webkit-animation:spin .5s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:spin .5s linear infinite;
animation:spin .5s linear infinite;
} @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}}
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}}`
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}}
```

But Say instead of it spinning automatically on the page load that I could press a button with an id of one and it would start to spin, and if I press a second button with an id of two, it would spin even faster then the first.

I am not sure how to achieve this. I did see where some people pointed out that you can change the css of an element using javascript but am unsure on how to achieve this especially on a button click. I want it to be something like `getElementById(spinning).style.property =` but on button click and just changing the speed of the rotation of my element.

Comment: play the snippet below. you can add 2 classes and toggle like below answer.

Comment: It's not been since forever ago that any webkit or Firefox browser has needed those prefixed properties.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to change the `animation-duration` CSS property dynamically with JavaScript.

```js
var rotors = document.querySelector(".rotors");

function fast() {
  rotors.style.animationDuration = ".2s";
}
 
function slow() {
  rotors.style.animationDuration = ".5s";
}
```

```css
.rotors {
  height: 50px; /* for demo purpose */
  width: 50px;  /* for demo purpose */
  animation: spin .5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="fast()">Fast</button>
  <button onclick="slow()">Slow</button>
</p>
<img class="rotors" src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_489361.png" />
```

Comment: You are a legend. This helped me a ton.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add 2 buttons and use it to change the classes like below:

```js
function startSpinning(){
  var spDiv = document.getElementById('test');
  if(spDiv.classList.contains('rotorsFast')){
    spDiv.classList.remove('rotorsFast');
    spDiv.classList.add('rotors');
  }else{
  spDiv.classList.add('rotors');
  }
  
}

function startSpinningFast(){
  var spDiv = document.getElementById('test');
  if(spDiv.classList.contains('rotors')){
    spDiv.classList.remove('rotors');
    spDiv.classList.add('rotorsFast');
  }else{
   spDiv.classList.add('rotorsFast');
  }
}
```

```css
.rotors {
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: spin .5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin .5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin .5s linear infinite;
}
.rotorsFast {
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  left: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: spin .2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin .2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin .2s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

` @keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width:20px">apple</div>
<button onclick="startSpinning()">spin</button>
<button onclick="startSpinningFast()">spin Fast</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice spot to use a [CSS custom variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*). When the button is clicked, we toggle a secondary class on the `.rotors` `div`. When the `faster` class is present, the custom variable resets the animation speed to the faster speed, which is automatically applied to the animation.

```js
const rotors = document.querySelector('.rotors'); 
const btn = document.querySelector('.rotorButton');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rotors.classList.toggle('faster')
});
```

```css
.rotors {
  --spin-speed: 2s; /* Initial speed */
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: spin var(--spin-speed) linear infinite;  
}

.rotors.faster {
  --spin-speed: .5s; /* Faster speed  */
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotors">text</div>
<button class="rotorButton" type="button">Toggle Rotor Speed</button>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9wmjdtu/6/)